# Find object using value of the object in an object array javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose you have an object array as so:

```
[
{name: 'John',age: 30},
{name: 'Mike',age: 40},
{name: 'Steve',age: 50},
]
```

If you have the value of one of the items in the object, for example `steve` how can I then get the entire object with the `steve` belongs to in Javascript.